# 'tuple' object has no attribute 'loc' in def

Tags: python, mapreduce, tuples

I am working on an assignment regarding map_reduce, but have some issues when running the function def.

```
a = [((1,1/4), [2,3,4]), ((2, 1/4), [3,4]), ((3,1/4), [1,4]), ((4,1/4),[2])]
```

accessing the elements outside of the function works well:

[image: Result from accessing element]

So I moved forward to put them into a function:

```
def mapper_PR(Data): 
  node = Data[0][0][0]
  pr = Data[0][0][1]
  dest = Data[0][1]
  degree = len(dest)

  return [[i, pr/degree] for i in dest]

import defs
mapped_values = map(defs.mapper_PR, a)
mapped_values

partition_value = list(itertools.chain(*mapped_values))
```

However, when I define it as a function and import the .py file back to google collab, it starts to have problem

This is the error code I received:

[image: error code]

How can I rectify this issue?

Comment: Next time please post text instead of images, but your issue is `map` will iterate over `a` and pass each element to your `mapper_PR` function (i.e. the first call will be `mapper_PR(((1,1/4), [2,3,4]))`). It won't pass the whole list at once (in which case `map` would be pretty useless).

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

Modifing the code solved the problem.

```
import itertools

def mapper_PR(Data): 
  node = Data[0][0][0]
  pr = Data[0][0][1]
  dest = Data[0][1]
  degree = len(dest)

  return ([i, pr/degree] for i in dest)


a = [((1,1/4), [2,3,4]), ((2, 1/4), [3,4]), ((3,1/4), [1,4]), ((4,1/4),[2])]
mapped_values = mapper_PR(a)
mapped_values

partition_value = list(itertools.chain(*mapped_values))
partition_value
```

Comment: Might be better to use a generator in the function and skip the intermediate variable

Comment: @mozway can you explain more on which part are you referring?

Comment: @`Himanshu Pingulkar`, is it possible for me to still keep the map function? As subsequently I'd need to do iteration

Comment: @Himanshu instead of `return [...]`, if you do `return (...)`, this will create a generator and the values will not be computed until consumed by chain. This is more memory efficient as there is no intermediate list.

Comment: @mozway great suggestions! Any way to use generator in the main function.

Comment: @ppotatomato the map function is the one causing the error,  figuring out a way to use it.